# Shuffling two lists together with no repetitions in the second list

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have 2 vectors of strings (one is roughly 1/3 the size of the other). I am trying to implement an algorithm that will randomly shuffle the two vectors together. In the resulting vector items that were previously in vector A can follow each other, but the ones that were in vector B cannot.

For example if every element in vector A is "FOO" and every element in vector B is "BAR", then the resulting vector might be {"FOO","FOO","BAR","FOO","BAR","FOO","FOO","BAR"}

As you can see "FOO" may repeat but "BAR" must not

This is roughly what I have so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> a(1000, "FOO");
std::vector<std::string> b(300, "BAR");
std::vector<std::string> result;

bool resultIsValid();

void mergeVectors()
{
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937 generator(seed);

    result = a;
    result.insert(result.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
    while (!resultIsValid())
    {
        std::shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), generator);
    }
}

bool resultIsValid()
{
    for(int i=0; i<result.size()-2; ++i)
        if (result[i] == "BAR" && result[i+1] == "BAR")
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This is not the actual code but this should give an idea. When I run this, the program goes into the endless loop because the actual numbers of strings are much higher (in the 10000 range) and it never gets the valid vector. There is always at least one of "BAR" repeating sequentially. Would anyone be able to suggest a better alternative then to just keep rechecking the created vector for duplicates of "BAR" ? Am I making this more complicated than it has to be ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort

Comment: In all seriousness though, I would probably approach this as follows: Iterate through every "gap" in the resulting list. At each point, insert (or not) an element from `B` with the probability of inserting being equal to the number of remaining elements in `B` divided by the number of remaining gaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resulting list consists of `"BAR","FOO"` and `"FOO"` elements. For example

```
{"FOO","FOO","BAR","FOO","BAR","FOO","FOO","BAR","FOO"}
```

can be split up to

```
"FOO" | "FOO" | "BAR","FOO" | "BAR","FOO" | "FOO" | "BAR","FOO"
```

which can be compressed to

```
{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
```

where 0 means single element and 1 means a transition from `"BAR"` to `"FOO"`.

The number of `0`s and `1`s is invariant, so one can generate a vector containing these and shuffle it.

The only problem is at the end, where a single `"BAR"` is also valid (the same problem arises at the beginning if you look at `"BAR","FOO"` as primitive element).

This can be solved if the vector containing `"FOO"` is increased by 1 dummy element (sentinel).  The resulting list always ends with an element of `"FOO"` but is otherwise truly random.  But we can safely remove the last element since this is our dummy.

A simple code (without templating on Iterators and Allocators) implementing the algorithm could look like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> mergeVectors(std::vector<std::string> const& canvas,
                                      std::vector<std::string> const& sprinkle)
{
  assert (canvas.size() + 1>= sprinkle.size()); // otherwise impossible

  std::vector<int> transitions; // 1 for [sprinkle, canvas]
                                // 0 for single [canvas]

  // sprinkle.size() times [canvas, sprinkle]
  transitions.insert(transitions.end(), sprinkle.size(), 1);
  // rest is [canvas].
  transitions.insert(transitions.end(), canvas.size() - sprinkle.size() + 1, 0);

  // There is a problem with the last element since this always is from canvas
  // as well.  So we set the last canvas to a sentinel element which is always removed.
  // This way, we can ensure that the result is truly randomly distributed.

  std::mt19937 generator(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
  std::shuffle(transitions.begin(), transitions.end(), generator);

  bool last_is_sprinkle = transitions.back(); transitions.pop_back();

  std::vector<std::string> result;
  auto canvas_it   = canvas.begin();
  auto sprinkle_it = sprinkle.begin();

  for (auto t : transitions) {
    if (t) result.push_back(*sprinkle_it++);
    result.push_back(*canvas_it++);
  }
  if (last_is_sprinkle)
    result.push_back(*sprinkle_it);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 This assessment is made of pure **win**. I honestly wouldn't care if the code following the description of this solution was riddled with bugs. The sheer recognition of shuffling a predefined known set of transition states and using that shuffle for the basis of the emitted sequence pattern is one-step-shy of glorious, and should *seriously* be considered by the OP.

Comment: [See it live](http://ideone.com/6AFXP3). Again, I wish I could up-vote this more than once. I didn't account for the head-BAR (and I probably should have) but still, the algorithm is *beautiful*.

Comment: +1 I agree that this algorithm is *beautiful*, and much more so than my answer. It would be interesting to benchmark one against the other, which I'll do when I get the chance.

Comment: It occurs to me that, rather than doing a shuffle (which might take quite a lot of expensive random number generation to do properly), once one knew the number of '1's and '0's to put in the result vector, one could use the same sort of selection process as I used in my answer to decide probabilistically which element in the result should be a '1' or '0', based on the number of each that remain to be allocated. If the selection was done that way, both algorithms should require about the same number of random numbers to be generated, and so they should benchmark about the same.

Comment: Generating and shuffling a list of `0`s and `1`s indeed isn't the smartest way.  The [Reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) algorithm used inplace by Simon could be a little bit faster and is correct.  I honestly haven't known this algorithm a few hours ago, wasn't sure if it's correct and I have no idea how to proof such random things (not yet studying...). Simons algorithm is probably better and the mine may be easier to understand, but both are equivalent and `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you! I have chosen to accept this answer, mainly because of a very good concise and well-illustrated explanation. Of course I like the algorithm as well.

Answer (score 2):

We can compute the probability that the next element in the resulting vector should be from A or B based on the number of elements remaining to be allocated from each of A and B and randomly select the next element from either A or B based on that probability.

The probablity of selecting the next element from list A is always 100% if the last element selected was from list B (which prevents consecutive elements from B).

If the number of elements left in A is equal to the number of elements left in B, the probability that one should get the next element from B is 100% if the last element added to the resulting list was from A.

Otherwise, the probability of selecting an element from A should be equal to `(A.length() - B.length())/A.length()`, assuming that we're taking the elements out of A and B as we put them in the resulting vector, so their lengths decrease to zero over the process. We could determine if the element should come from list A or list B by testing a randomly generated value between 0 and 1 against this probability.

This should guarantee that the As and Bs are evenly shuffled, which one could test by running the program many times and comparing the number of Bs in each half of the resulting vector.

(EDIT)

I thought it was quicker to test this algorithm in Python, so here's my Python implementation:

```
from random import random

def intersperse(a,b):
    la = len(a)
    lb = len(b)
    ia = 0
    ib = 0
    bWasLast = False
    res = []
    while (ia < la) or (ib < lb):
        if bWasLast:
            res.append(a[ia])
            ia += 1
            bWasLast = False
        elif ((lb - ib) > (la - ia)) and not bWasLast:
            res.append(b[ib])
            ib += 1
            bWasLast = True
        else:
            laRemaining = la - ia
            lbRemaining = lb - ib
            probA = (laRemaining - lbRemaining)/laRemaining
            if random() < probA:
                res.append(a[ia])
                ia += 1
                bWasLast = False
            else:
                res.append(b[ib])
                ib += 1
                bWasLast = True
    return res
```

Test code is as follows:

```
A = 'a'*10000
B = 'b'*3000

sumBLeft = 0
sumBRight = 0

for n in range(100):
    r = intersperse(A,B)
    sumBLeft += sum([1 for x in r[:len(r)//2] if x == 'b'])
    sumBRight += sum([1 for x in r[len(r)//2:] if x == 'b'])

print (sumBLeft/sumBRight)
```

The output from this program showed that the number of 'b's in the left side of the result was only 0.08% greater than the number of 'b's in the right side of the result for my test run, confirming that the distribution of 'b's through the result vector is even.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is the simple fact that as you progress down the list the mandatory A-after-B requirement will cause the list to be B-heavier on the tail than the head, even if it honors the no-two-successive B's throughout. The simple fact that the earlier part of the list has a higher probably of generating successive A's (because there are more of them available then) than B's makes this an inescapable artifact of the algorithm, especially if you're unfortunate enough to have A.size() reach B.size(), at which time you *must* oscillate A-B-A-B.. until finished.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You're quite right. The probability of selecting an item from A should actually be `(A.length() - B.length())/A.length()`, so I've edited my answer to reflect that. I've also tested the algorithm and it does indeed give even numbers of "B" elements in the first and second halves of the resulting vector, on average.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your code, you are shuffling for good luck until the mix you get is a valid one. My approach would be something like the following:

Be `foo` the vector with the "FOO" items and `bar` the vector with the "BAR" items, and be `F` and `B` their respective sizes.
Any bar item must be preceded by a "FOO" item, except if the "BAR" item is the first item in the result sequence. So if we draw together the "BAR"s and their preceding "FOO"s, we get `B` "FOOBAR" sequences (or `B-1`, if we start with a "BAR") and `F-B` (or `F-(B-1)`) "FOO"s in between.
The probability that a result sequence starts with a "BAR" item is `B/(F+1)`.

I'd first make a pattern vector for the mix of "BAR" and "FOO" items, and after that mix together the real result vector. The pattern would consist of "FOOBAR" and "FOO" items, since a "BAR" item must be preceded by a "FOO" except if the result sequence starts with "BAR"

Pseudocode:

```
bool startsWithBar = B < (random * (F+1));
//if the sequence starts with a BAR, there are B-1 FOOBAR items
int nFOOBAR = B - (startsWithBar ? 1 : 0); 
int nFOO = F - nFOOBAR;

vector<char> pattern(nFOOBAR, 'm'); //m for mix - FOOBAR = FOO followed by a BAR
pattern.insert(pattern.end(), nFOO, 'f');

shuffle(pattern);
shuffle(foo);
shuffle(bar);

vector<string> result;
result.reserve(F+B);

auto itBar = begin(bar);
auto itFoo = begin(foo);

//fill the result according to the pattern
if (startsWithBar)
  result.push_back(*itBar++);

for (char patt : pattern)
{
  switch (patt)
  {
    case 'f': //"FOO"
      result.push_back(*itFoo++);
      break;
    case 'm': //"FOOBAR"
      result.push_back(*itFoo++);
      result.push_back(*itBar++);
      break;
  }
}
```

For you example `{"FOO","FOO","BAR","FOO","BAR","FOO","FOO","BAR"}`, the pattern would be `{'f', 'm', 'm', 'f', 'm'}`

Comment: Nice approach, but the probability that a result sequence starts with a "BAR" item is **not** exactly B/F. Even if B=F, the start can be `FOO` (the list is "FOO,BAR,FOO,BAR,...").

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be `B/(F+B)`, I'll correct that.

Comment: This is incorrect too since the list can look like "BAR,FOO,...,BAR,FOO,FOO,BAR,...,FOO,BAR" where the position of "FOO,FOO" can vary (and it is most likely not at the front). I *think* B/(F+1) could be correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's been too long since I did that kind of math ;) `B/(F+1)` looks good, though, since we can apply your idea of the "sentinel foo" put in front of the result sequence and removed after that.

Answer (score 0):

If your second vector `v2` is shorter than `v1` you have to copy each element of `v2` into the output vector `vout` and append one or more elements of `v1` each time. One solution would be, to enumerate all possible indices of `v1` and randomly erase them until only as many indices are left as elements are in `v2`. So, the difference between two adjacent indices is the number of elements in `v1` that you insert into `vout` after an element of `v2`. For example:

```
    using size_type = std::vector<std::string>::size_type;

    std::vector<size_type> vid(v1.size());
    std::iota(begin(vid), end(vid), 0);
    std::random_shuffle(begin(vid), end(vid));
    vid.erase(std::next(begin(vid), v2.size()), end(vid));
    std::sort(begin(vid), end(vid));

    size_type id_last = 0;
    for(size_type i = 0; i < vid.size(); ++i) {
        vout.insert(end(vout), std::next(begin(v1), id_last),
                                                 std::next(begin(v1), vid[i]));
        vout.push_back(v2[i]);
        id_last = vid[i];
    }
    vout.insert(end(vout), std::next(begin(v1), vid.back()), end(v1));
```

This is probably not the fastest method, but it should outline the idea behind it. I believe this whole index management can also be rewritten using some iterator adaptors like in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html). Also, if you don't need the original string vectors after merging, you can move the strings instead of copying them.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to do as follows:

- Shuffle A.
- Initialise the resulting vector C as shuffled B. At this point the elements in C are `|B|`, and you know you will have to put at least `|B|-1` elements from A between them.
- Pop elements from the shuffled A vector, inserting them in the appropriate positions within C, so as to avoid repeated B elements within C.
- Finish off perform `|A|-(|B|-1)` insertions into the C vector, at random positions, using the remaining elements within A.

Suppose you have:

```
A = {FOO1, FOO2, FOO3, FOO4, FOO5}
B = {BAR1, BAR2, BAR3}
```

Step 1 & 2:

```
A = {FOO4, FOO3, FOO1, FOO5, FOO2}
C = {BAR3, BAR1, BAR2}
```

Step 3:

```
A = {FOO1, FOO5, FOO2}
C = {BAR3, FOO4, BAR1, FOO3, BAR2}
```

Step 4:

```
C = {FOO1, FOO5, BAR3, FOO4, BAR1, FOO3, FOO2, BAR2}
```